# Getting events on delete and paste in textbox jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am using jquery on asp.net mvc. I have textbox on page and I hooked up handler for keyup event of textbox. When user deletes the text or pastes text into it, i do not get the handler called.

Please help me how to handle this.

**EDIT:** Also I want to get the value when user pastes the value using mouse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="mytextbox" />

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function () {
     $("#mytextbox")keyup(function(evt) {
       evt = evt || event;
       switch (evt.keyCode) {
          case 8: //Backspace was pressed
            alert("Backspace");
            break;
          case 46: //Delete was pressed
            alert("Delete");
            break;
          case 67:
            if (evt.ctrlKey) {
               alert("Ctrl-C");
            }
            break;
          case 86:
            if (evt.ctrlKey) {
              alert("Ctrl-V");

            }
            break;
          default:
            alert(evt.keyCode);
            break;
       }
     });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: The question was how to get it to work when the user pastes text into the box.  This won't work in that instance.  (Though the down vote wasn't mine.)

Comment: @John: Apologies, but the OP stated in the question that he already had a `keyup` event but that it wasn't getting called on those circumstances. I just don't see how his post is at all addressed by this answer.

Comment: lol.  The question specifically asks how to handle text pasting using keyup event.   Now clearly you can handle pasting text via mouse events as well.  But it didnt specify using a mouse event.  Onchange doesnt necessarly specify that text was pasted.  I simply answered the question as I interpreted it.

Comment: Your question has made me realize that i have to handle paste using mouse. :)

Comment: @John: I promise I meant no offense. But actually, the question specifically states that when a user deletes or pastes text that a `keyup` (that he already has) isn't getting called. I interpreted that as wanting to know when anything changes in the box.

Comment: Hey Lance I understand completely...We just both interpreted the question differently, and thats whats cool about this site.  Many opinions.  It just I appreciate a comment when downvoted, because I like to know what I did wrong (it helps me and the person asking the question learn)

Comment: Your solution is working. I have upvoted you for the effort. Now please provide solution for the mouse right click and paste scenario. thanks.

Comment: mohang...yeah Im still thinking about that one...there is a paste and copy event but it is not cross browser compatable.  see here  http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: Never mind. I just took care of it on blur event. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your `keyup` to a `change` and see if that helps.

**- EDIT -**

Have a look at http://archive.devx.com/dhtml/articles/nz012402/nz012402-6.asp as well. most of this is covered in great detail.

Comment: change event gives me the value after changing the value and textbox losing the focus. I want the value as soon as user enters at each keystroke.

Comment: @Mohang: Understood. Did you look over the article on masking input? It should have the information you're looking for.

Comment: Actually I opened it and I was not having the time read through all that text now as I have this thing to be delivered urgently. sorry.